# MacOS 10.12, WKWebView problem with file input

Tags: macos, webkit, wkwebview

I develop an application with WKWebView for web application. Native app is just container for web application.

XCode: 11.3.1,
Deployment target: MacOS 10.12

10.13 - 10.15 - work's as expected, but 10.12 can't upload files throw input type="file"

runOpenPanelWith implementation

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runOpenPanelWith parameters: WKOpenPanelParameters, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping ([URL]?) -> Void) {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        openPanel.begin { (result) in
            NSLog("Selected result " + result.rawValue.description)
            if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
                if let url = openPanel.url {
                    completionHandler([url])
                }
            } else if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.cancel {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Debug from js:

```
window.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    console.log(event.clipboardData.items);
)
// null

fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log(fileInput.files[0].size);
})
// 0
```

Doesn't work throw copy-paste and doesn't work throw open panel.

What broken in 10.12 or maybe I need something specific for 10.12?

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you solve the problem?